# Biomechanics statics of an push-up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, biophysics, statics

So I am really struggling with a statics problem about calculating forces and torques of an exercise.

So I need to calculate the forces acting on the feet and hands, as well as the torques, for 2 static push-up positions. I've linked the 2 static push-up positions at the bottom.

How do I go about this?

BTW: I know I have not given any lengths, angles, and so on, because I'm more interested in the way you would write up the equations step by step rather than a final answer.

**My thoughts:**

1. I know there are 3 forces [Hand, feet, and weight(at the center of mass)]
2. My assumption is that there is static equilibrium.
3. Since it's a static problem there's no acceleration
4. I know for the **start position**(second picture) there is an angle theta which plays a factor

[image: Finish position]
[image: Start position]

**Thank you in advance, Thomas**

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There are two equations for static equilibrium, (1) the sum of the forces equals zero and (2) the sum of the moments (torques) equals zero.

For the first equation you only need the persons weight. For the second equation you need the location of the person's center of mass. You will need to apply the second equation twice, once for each diagram, because the horizontal location of the center of mass of the person will be different for the two positions. The angle comes into play for the second diagram.

Hope this helps.